# Is there a way to update a deeply nested value of this structure via recursive method

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am attempting to update this array of objects based on the object key. Each key maps to a registry which holds a method to format the data and return it and then update the object key. This recursive function works but cant handle an object key which has a nested object.

```
 [
  {
    "myData": "test",
    "nestedArr": [
      {
        "hello": "test",
        "check": "test",
        "nestedObject": {
          "hello": "hello",
          "nestedArr": [
            {
              "test": {
                "value": "updateMe"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my current implementation

```
const parse = async (arr) => {
  return await Promise.all(
    arr.map(async (obj) => {
      await Promise.all(
        Object.keys(obj).map(async (value) => {
          if (Array.isArray(obj[value])) {
            await parse(obj[value]);
          }

          try {
            const method = registry[value];
            const data = await method(obj, value);
            obj[value] = data;
          } catch (error) {}
        })
      );

      return obj;
    })
  );
};
```

UPDATED:

```
const parse = async (arr) => {
  return await Promise.all(
    arr.map(async (obj) => {
      await Promise.all(
        Object.keys(obj).map(async (value) => {
          if (Array.isArray(obj[value])) {
            await parse(obj[value]);
          }

          try {
            if (typeof obj[value] === "object") {
              await parse([obj[value]]);
            }
          } catch (error) {}

          try {
            const method = registry[value];
            const data = await method(obj, value);
            obj[value] = data;
          } catch (error) {}
          
        })

      );

      return obj;
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: If `obj[value]` is a non-array object, you need to loop over the keys and values, calling `parse()` on each of them.

Comment: if i call parse on each key it will fail as it expects an array

Comment: You should redesign `parse()` so it can accept any type, and do the type checking first, before the loop.

Comment: @Barmar pointed me in the right direction, updated the result. Works great not too concerned on the performance aspect as this result will be cached in redis

Comment: Put the solution in an Answer below, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar pointed me in the right direction, updated the result. Works great not too concerned on the performance aspect as this result will be cached in redis

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).